# Get download size of the webpage

Tags: php, curl, web, html

I have the code to get the size of the webpage.

Problem with this code is, it is not returning the page size if the site have HTTPS

How to get the total size of the URL or webpage in php

```
$url = 'facebook.com';        
$curl = curl_init($url);       
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);    
$subject = curl_exec($curl);  
print("Download size: " . curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD) .'<br>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you're using HTTPS shouldn't affect any follow-up calls to `curl_getinfo`.

I suspect the problem here is that you haven't specified that Curl should follow redirects - fetching `facebook.com` actually returns a 301 redirect to `https://facebook.com/`. Unless you tell Curl that it should follow it, it'll give up after the first request. In this case, because the response is just a redirect header, the body is empty, hence your 0-byte size.

If you specify

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

then it will follow the redirect, and you'll get the correct filesize (182227, for me at least).

Comment: $url = 'https://facebook.com/';  
$curl = curl_init($url);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  
$subject = curl_exec($curl);  
//get the download size of page
print("Download size: " . curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD) .'<br>');

Comment: Not sure what else to add - your code works fine for me. It might be worth checking if your server definitely has outbound network access for both HTTP and HTTPS traffic. You might get some more information by calling `echo curl_error($curl)`

Comment: Thank You.. Its Working fine in server, something wrong with my localhost